# How to store anonymous SQL parameters in dbeaver?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

In DBeaver 21.3.3 I can use variables like:

```
@set myvar= 'something'
select * from mytable where col = :myvar
```

But how to do this for anonymous SQL parameters:

```
select * from mytable where col = ?
```

In Windows | Preferences | Editors | SQL Editor | SQL Processing | Parameter section | I checked "Anonymous SQL parameters" and left other parameters untouched.

Now every time "Bind parameters" dialog opens and I have to type in parameters.
How can I store these bindings in script?